# PHP check next date in equation

Tags: php, date, strtotime

The following code is supposed to check for the first saturday of next month the remove 6 days from it and determine if that todays date is less than that date calculated. It is not working. The IF statement is triggering regardless of whether todays date has exceeded the first saturday of next month - 6 days or not.

```
<?php $monthdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 day', strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('+1 month')))); 
if ($monthdate < date)
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: ever had an idea of printing the result out instead of just checking it in if statement?

Comment: as well as all intermediate results, to see if any of them returns not expected value?

Comment: `var_dump($monthdate)` and `var_dump($date)` and `var_dump($monthdate < date)`

Comment: Yes the values are not timestamps, thats the problem. $monthdate should be a UNIX timestamp, how do I make it one. And date should be todays date as a UNIX timestamp and is not. Any ideas?

Comment: `date` is a constant. Is that at typo you made *here*? If not, then you would have gotten a notice (or is it a warning?) if you have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` and turned on displaying of errors. (consider that a hint ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict between 2 functions and also the date not being properly formatted as a time stamp. For the community I give the answer.

```
<?php $monthdate = date(strtotime('first saturday', strtotime('-8 day', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))))); 

if ($monthdate < time())
```

`$monthdate` returns a UNIX timestamp of the first saturday of next month. The function `strtotime(date("01-m-Y"))` is required to make sure that if todays date is higher in day terms the first saturday of the next month ie. if the first saturday of this month is the 5th and next month the 2nd, that it gets the 2nd as the first saturday not the 9th. Simple mathmatical adjustment of where to begin its search.

This is then subtracted by 8 days and compared with a UNIX timestamp of the current date and `time time();`

**Purpose**

Providing an online booking calendar that takes bookings on the first saturday of each month.